# Eclipse builds a too heavy binary file

Tags: c, eclipse, binary

I've just ported a C project from Kdevelop to eclipse, the binary that before was around 600kb now is 5000kb and I don't know which is my mistake.
I am using the option to autogenerate the Makefile, could it be the reason?

thanks!

Comment: How do you port it? With the option "File->New->Makefile Project With Existing Code" ?

Comment: Nop. I created a complete new Project : New-> C Project -> Cross- compile Project, then I import the project files : Import->file system, I configure all the includes, library, compiler... And I'm using the makefile generated by eclipse. The compilation is ok , but as I said it is too heavy and the application doesn't work as expected

Comment: You need to compare the old (Kdevelop) and the new (Eclipse) makefie, obviously links the second a lot of libraries ...

Comment: Ok thanks I am going to do it

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like it's being built with full debug symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved simply using the original makefile from kdevelop instead of the autogenerated eclipse makefile